# No results from traceid from sys.fn_trace_getinfo(0);

Tags: sql-server, trace

```
 SELECT DISTINCT(eventid) FROM sys.fn_trace_geteventinfo(#);
```

The above command returns no results.  There should be a bunch of trace event id being traced.

Comment: What does the content of `sys.traces` look like? You should start there instead of the functions...

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have no traces running on your server.

The function mentioned in your post title is:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.fn_trace_getinfo(0)
```

Using either a `0` or a `NULL` as the parameter will produce a listing of all running traces.  That list could look like this:

```
traceid property    value
1   1   2
1   2   D:\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\log_6215.trc
1   3   20
1   4   NULL
1   5   1
2   1   1
2   2   NULL
2   3   NULL
2   4   NULL
2   5   1
```

However, if you use another `traceid` it will only show the description rows for that trace. (Or no values if the `traceid` is invalid.)

The other function that you show was:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(eventid) FROM sys.fn_trace_geteventinfo(#);
```

Using a `traceid`, this will produce a list of event ids for the `traceid`.  An invalid `traceid` will return no rows.

Since you are not getting any return on your queries, then there should be no traces running.